# How to save List<String> in List<Model>?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm Making Quiz System in Flutter

**Question Model**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class QuestionModel with ChangeNotifier{

  final String questionTitle;
  final String questionImage;
  final int questionPoint;
  final List<String> questionAnswer;
  final String rightAnswer;

  QuestionModel({
    @required this.questionTitle,
    @required this.questionImage,
    @required this.questionPoint,
    @required this.questionAnswer,
    @required this.rightAnswer,
  });

}
```

i want add answer to Question

but when i try this :

```
  List<String> answerText = [];

  var question = QuestionModel(
    questionTitle: '',
    rightAnswer: '',
    questionPoint: 0,
    questionImage: '',
    questionAnswer: answerText 
  );
```

On save ... All question get same List of Answer :(

how can i solve this ? :(

Comment: Welll ... I can't understand too many things from your code, but if that's your code, you'll get every time the same blank list, since it's the last value for your answerText before you add it to your object. And also, you shouldn't mix your model with a change notifier and also your variables in provider class shouldn't be final. Those variables will suffer changes in your provider. You should create a simple PODO class where you create your model and a simple provider class where you create your logic and then you can access your variables in ui to to whatever you want. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```dart
 List<QuestionModel> questions = new List<QuestionModel>();
    List<String> answerText = ["a", "c"];

    var question = QuestionModel(
        questionTitle: "my first question",
        questionAnswer: answerText
    );
    questions.add(question);
    print(questions[0].questionAnswer[0]); // get first question (index 0 and not 1) and print its first answer
```

And don't set the fields as final if you intend to change values in the future

```
class QuestionModel with ChangeNotifier {
  String questionTitle;
  String questionImage;
  int questionPoint;
  List<String> questionAnswer;
  String rightAnswer;

  QuestionModel({
    this.questionTitle,
    this.questionImage,
    this.questionPoint,
    this.questionAnswer,
    this.rightAnswer,
  });
}
```

Maybe you make a confusion between your **list of questions** and **your list of answer**. Each question has multiple answers (or choices). So you also need to create a List for all of your questions.